# What is the maximum number of current members in a group CA that MKA can support?

Tags: protocol-design, protocol-analysis

The MACsec standard (IEEE 802.1AE-2018) states "The number of SCIs (and hence the number of SSCIs) is ultimately limited by the maximum number of current members in a group CA that MKA can support (less than 100) but is likely to be further limited by the port-based network control application (see Clause 7 of IEEE Std 802.1X-2010)."

An SCI (Secure Channel Identifier) is defined as "comprising a 48-bit MAC address concatenated with a 16-bit Port Identifier".  It is not the constraining feature.

What is the actual limit for the number of current members?  What is this limit based on?